# How to make JQuery to treat Ajax response as plain text instead of JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am consuming an API that return JSON. The JSON syntax returned by API is broken and I have no control to get it fixed.

I am using JQuery Ajax call and it returns *500 - Internal Server Error*. I want to get API response and plain text and fix the JSON syntax. it just has an additional comma at the end which I can remove. But I am not able to get the response as plain text.

I have tried several approaches such as setting content-type and/or accept headers to plain text using dataType to plain text as below. My code is as below.

```
$.ajax({
    url: apiUrl + "/" + customerId + "/accounts/" + accountId,
    data: "client_id=" + clientId,
    dataType: 'text',
    type: 'GET',
    async: true,
    statusCode: {
        404: function (response) {
            console.log('Invalid Transaction details');
        },
        200: function (response) {
            //response processing code here
        }
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, status, errorThrown) {
        //Error handling routine
    }
});
```

**Update 1**
The API works fine when directly called from browser or fiddler. That's how I come to know that JSON syntax is broken.

Comment: how can we know, why somebodies API is returning with an error? please, tell us, wich API do you using, how can we reproduce your problem, and what is your code what you are using?

Comment: 1. Validate the response using online JSON validators. 2. Validate your modified response using online JSON validators. 3. Change your code accordingly. 4. Please post code too to avoid an avalanche of down-votes :)

Comment: @lolka_bolka I understand your concern. Unfortunately, I cannot share the API URL here. However, I just want to know if it's possible to make jQuery treat the JSON as plain text. And how?

Comment: Can you provide the code you are using to read the json as text?

Comment: I have updated the question to make it more readable and posted my code fragment.

Comment: can you tell what error and status code is given wenn error callback is executed?

Comment: @Tuan The jqXHR status is 0 and no error message is shown.

Comment: If you are getting 500 from the server, there is nothing you are going to be able to do on your side.

Comment: @MikeBrant, It works perfect when I call teh API from browser or fiddler. So I think that the issue is not with API but with JQuery call.

Comment: @theark  Well if you are getting a 500 in response to your jQuery AJAX call, I am wondering if you are making a malformed request.  Really impossible for us to know without understanding API requirements.

Comment: @MikeBrant I copied the url that is seen in the network tab in the developer tools for this request and tried it on the browser directly, and it gave me the json response.

Comment: @theark see my answer. your code works fine.

Answer (score 5):

### your code runs well, there has to be another error

> [See my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hzhk2eg7/)

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://ip.jsontest.com/',
    dataType: 'text',
    type: 'GET',
    async: true,
    statusCode: {
        404: function (response) {
            alert(404);
        },
        200: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, status, errorThrown) {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

It returns json from a test API as a string all fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
// the URL for the request
url: apiUrl + "/" + customerId + "/accounts/" + accountId,

// the data to send (will be converted to a query string)
data: "client_id=" + clientId,

// whether this is a POST or GET request
type: "GET",

// the type of data we expect back
//Use JSON so that the browser knows how to format and transfer the data correctly, you 
//can always converted to plain text once you receive it
dataType: 'json',

async: true,

// code to run if the request succeeds;
// the response is passed to the function
//output everything to the console to inspect the response that way you can see everything
//the API sends back. I'm assuming you know how to Inspect Element and look at the Console  
//on your browser
success: function( response ) {
    console.log(response)
},

// code to run if the request fails; the raw request and
// status codes are passed to the function
error: function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
    alert( "Sorry, there was a problem!" );
    console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
    console.log( "Status: " + status );
    console.dir( xhr );
},

// code to run regardless of success or failure
complete: function( xhr, status ) {
   console.log(xhr, status)
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You said

> The jqXHR status is 0 and no error message is shown

and

> I copied the url that is seen in the network tab in the developer tools for this request and tried it on the browser directly, and it gave me the json response.

in your comments, which leads me to believe this is a CORS issue on top of the `500 - Internal Server Error` you are experiencing on the server side.

If you want to get the server response as plain text (and you can somehow craft your API request to not trip a 500 error), then use a server-side [wrapper/proxy](http://jsonpwrapper.com/) (or [PHP + cURL](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/754444/POST-JSON-Data-With-PHP-cURL-wrapper-class)) to get your data from the 3rd-party site as text, filter it or otherwise fix it, then `eval()` it (at your own risk) as a proper JSON object.